# Не получается создать и сохранить файл(Android)

Tags: android, android-sdk

Вроде как и банальный код, ничего сложного

```
OutputStream outputStream  = openFileOutput(fileName, 0);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
        osw.write(editText.getText().toString());
        osw.close();
```

После выполнения на телефоне ничего не меняется(на смартфоне нет флешки): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `fileName` то покажите.

Answer (score 1):

**Manifest**

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Сам код записи.**

```
    File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); // получаем корневой путь
    sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "FileDir"); // добавляем свой каталог к пути
    sdPath.mkdirs(); // создаем каталог
    File sdFile = new File(sdPath, "NameFile");

try {
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sdFile)); // открываем поток для записи
      bw.write("Содержимое файла"); // пишем данные
      bw.close(); // закрываем поток
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Файл записан на" + sdFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Все работает, проверенно на личном опыте