# Сохранить файл в android

Tags: java, android

программа должна сохранять файл с данными которые ввели в поля логин и пароль, затем считывать их, писать их в другое поле, и если они соответствуют "adminadmin" выводить пуш уведомление, ошибок программа не выдаёт, но ничего не работает

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText etEnterPassword;
    EditText etEnterLogin;
    Button btnEnter;
    CheckBox cbEnter;
    TextView tvChecking;
    TextView tvCheck;
    private final static String FILE_MAIN_NAME = "contextFile";
    String data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etEnterLogin = findViewById(R.id.etEnter);
        etEnterPassword = findViewById(R.id.etEnterPassword);
        btnEnter = findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
        cbEnter = findViewById(R.id.cbEnter);
        btnEnter.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvCheck = findViewById(R.id.tvCheck);
        try {
            checkOut();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            check();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's not OK(checkMain)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void jsonWriter() throws IOException {

        String path = getFilesDir() + "contextFile.txt";
        File context = new File(getFilesDir(), FILE_MAIN_NAME);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        if (!context.exists()) {
            context.createNewFile();
        }
        // FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("contextFile.txt");
        //gson.toJson(getDataLogin(), fileWriter);
        // gson.toJson(getDataPassword(), fileWriter);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(context);
        fileOutputStream.write(getDataLogin().getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.write(getDataPassword().getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(getFilesDir() + "/contextFile.txt");
        int data = fileInputStream.read();
        String s = null;
        char n;
        while (data !=-1){
            n = (char) data;
            data = fileInputStream.read();
            s = s + n;
        }
        fileInputStream.close();
        tvCheck.setText(s);

    }

    public void checkOut() throws IOException {
        String check0 = jsonReader();
        tvCheck.setText(check0);

    }

    public String jsonReader() throws IOException {
        String path = getFilesDir() + "contextFile.txt";
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(getFilesDir() + "/contextFile.txt");
        int data = fileInputStream.read();
        if (data == -1){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "-1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        String s = null;
        char n;
        while (data !=-1){
            n = (char) data;
            data = fileInputStream.read();
            s = s + n;
        }
        fileInputStream.close();
        return s;
        //FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("contextFile.txt");
        //while (fileReader.ready()) {
        //   data = data + fileReader.read();
//
        // }
        // return data;
    }

    public void check() throws IOException {
        String check = jsonReader();
        if (check == "adminadmin") {
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           toast.show();
      }

    }

    public String getDataLogin() {
        String login = etEnterLogin.getText().toString();
        return (login);
    }

    public String getDataPassword() {
        String password = etEnterPassword.getText().toString();
        return (password);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnEnter:
                try {
                    jsonWriter();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's not OK(jsonWriter)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    check();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's not OK(check)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    checkOut();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's not OK(checkOut)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584226/Не-получается-создать-и-сохранить-файлandroid

Comment: При записи вы используете константу `FILE_MAIN_NAME = "contextFile"` - без расширения (`.txt`), а при чтении литерал `"/contextFile.txt"` и получается запись в один файл, а чтение из другого.